# Must a sequence in a metric space $X$ be a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

When I was reading about sequential compactness, I often encounter proofs like "treating something as a sequence, etc..". However, from my old knowledge from real analysis, sequences are often treated as functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. In the sense of a metric space, is it also true? Or we can pick randomly to form a sequence?

Comment: I think that you will have to be more precise in order to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I think you are imagining that a "function" is the same as a "simple rule".  This is not the case.  If you have any sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers, the map $n\mapsto a_n$ defines a function from $\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$.

Comment: And, conversely, if you have a function $f$ from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$ you have a sequence defined by $f(1), f(2), ...$.

Comment: Given any nonempty set $A$, we can define a sequence in $A$ to be a function $f:\Bbb{N}\to A$ (and a subsequence of $f$ can be defined as a composition $f\circ \nu$ where $\nu:\Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{N}$ is strictly increasing). If this isn't satisfactory then you'll have to clarify what your question is.